# Rust - can a struct have a mutable member?

Tags: struct, rust, godot, mutability

so basically i am making a struct that needs to a member to be mutable because that same member will be borrowed by another function that will change it, like this:

```
fn chunk(&mut self) -> gdnative::Ref<ArrayMesh>{
        let st = SurfaceTool::new();

//      st.begin(Mesh::PRIMITIVE_TRIANGLES);
        st.begin(Mesh::PRIMITIVE_LINES);
        

        for x in 0..self.size.0{
            for y in 0..self.size.1{
                for z in 0..self.size.2{
                    VoxelChunk::custom_voxel(
                        &st, 
                        Vector3::new(x as f32 + self.pos.x,y as f32  + self.pos.y,z as f32 + self.pos.z),
                        &self.data
                        );
                }
            }
        }
        

        st.generate_normals(false);
        let mesh: Ref<ArrayMesh> = st.commit(gdnative::Null::null(), Mesh::ARRAY_COMPRESS_DEFAULT).unwrap();
        godot_print!("commited mesh!");
        return mesh;
    }
```

the function:

```
fn custom_voxel(st:&Ref<SurfaceTool, Unique>, pos:Vector3, data: &mut Vec<u8>){
//it has a lot of stuff so im not gonna put in here 
}
```

and it gives me this, but i dont know how would i make that member into a mutable reference

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:114:7
    |
114 |                         &self.data
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
    |
    = note: expected mutable reference `&mut Vec<u8>`
                       found reference `&Vec<u8>`

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Comment: You need `&mut` instead of `&` to get a mutable reference.

Comment: Pass `&mut self.data` instead of `&self.data`.

Comment: ok, gonna try it now

Comment: worked, i really dont know why i didnt think of that

Comment: Please close the question if this is solved

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Moderators could close it, which also gives you an opportunity to edit the question and have it open again. What you could do is delete the question.